# How to see exactly why SQL error is shown in vis studio 2017

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

For my school coursework we have to use Vis studio for our database and I keep getting 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' when I am editing fields of the database. I assume it is because of improper variable pass through in my DAL but as it doesn't say what column is throwing the error i cant narrow it down. so is there a way to see exactly where in the SQL the error is being thrown.

Ive been looking around on google and i cant seem to find any way of checking. everything ive seen is how to do it in SQL server but im not aloud to use that for my coursework.

Comment: SqlException has Message field which will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: The `.Message` property on that `SqlException` should contain more details (i.e. the same message that management studio would display to you if you used that directly)

Answer (score 1):

The SQLException class has some properties, which can help you: Number property, which defines the number of the exception and Errors collection each item in which provides you an informaion about the errors.